# ios ipad UIPopoverController is showing empty with no errors

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to implement a UIPopoverController to able to share but when the UIPopoverController is view is showing empty and I don't any errors it all. Here is my code:

```
if ([self.activityPopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.activityPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {

    NSString *textToShare=@"I'm sharing this image";
    NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.imgToSend,textToShare,nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
     activityVC.excludedActivityTypes=@[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard ];


    activityVC.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        [self.activityPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    };

    if (self.activityPopoverController) {
        [self.activityPopoverController setContentViewController:activityVC];
    } else {
        self.activityPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
    }
    [self.activityPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[(UIControl *)sender frame]
                                                    inView:self.view
                                  permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                  animated:YES];

}
```

Any of you may know why this is wrong with my code?

I really appreciate your help.

UPDATE:

I add this line of code:

```
 [self.activityPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover animated:YES];
```

but it looks all chop off:

[image]

Comment: Are you setting contentSizeInPopover property on UIActivityViewController?

Comment: I'm not :( how do I do that?

Comment: @HelenaM, I don't think that is the cause, check my answer.

Comment: The  contentSize trick is misleading and you shouldn't set it. The system works out the contentSize for the activityViewController's popover. You are arbitrarily setting it to the contentSize for the viewController's view, which is not correct. I am sure your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
   NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:self.imgToSend,textToShare,nil];
   UIActivityViewController *activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                          initWithActivityItems:activityItems 
                                          applicationActivities:nil];
```

If `self.imgToSend` is `nil`, `activityItems` will be `nil` and you will get an empty popover. So you need to check that `self.imgToSend` is initialised. Try `NSLog("imgToSend: %@",self.imgToSend)` to check this case.

The array is nil because `nil` is the array terminator, so if your first object is `nil`, the system regards your array to be completed at that point and doesn't look beyond it (to `textToShare`, for instance)

And as the the docs say:

*activityItems*

> This array must not be nil and must contain at least one object.

You can check if I am correct by swapping your two array items around:

```
  NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc] 
                            initWithObjects:textToShare,self.imgToSend,nil];
```

*update*
In your update question, you have introduced this line:

```
[self.activityPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover     
                                             animated:YES];
```

and you claim that this fixes the activity PopoverController by populating it with items, but the controller's frame is badly set.

This line does indeed alter the frame of the popOver but for all the wrong reasons - you are arbitrarily setting the frame to the contentSizeForViewInPopover of your host viewController - which is *not* the viewController that is being displayed in the popOver. You might as well just put some arbitrary numbers in there, for example:

```
[self.activityPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize){300,400} 
                                             animated:YES];
```

That will also reshape your popover - but in neither case is this code responsible for the presence or absence of activityItems.

If activiyItems are now appearing, you must have changed something else as well. I suggest you now try to run your code with this line commented out:

```
// [self.activityPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover     
//                                              animated:YES];
```

And report what happens.

I am really sure that you problem lies with `self.imgToSend`. I can run your code *exactly* as it is in your question, with activiyItems appearing correctly, if I take care to replace `self.imgToSend` with a locally-set image object.

This succeeds:

```
     UIImage* image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
     NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:image,@"text",nil];
```

This fails (empty popOverController):

```
     UIImage* image= nil;
     NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:image,@"text",nil];
```

This succeeds:

```
     UIImage* image= nil;
     NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"text",image,nil];
```

This succeeds:

```
     UIImage* image= nil;
     NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"text",nil];
```

I suggest you just take out `self.imgToSend` and see if your activityItems populate correctly without it, then at least you will know where the problem lies.

Comment: the image is to attach in the message but is not nil

Comment: neither the array of activityitems is not nill

Comment: @Helena, Can you add an `NSLog` of your `activityItems` to your question. What happens if you just delete self.imgToSend from the array, how does it look then?

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The problem is not the array. The problem is how UIPopoverController is displaying in the view.

Comment: @HelenaM, You reported an empty popOver view, which is caused by an empty array. And your code works fine on my system so long as the img variable has correct content, so I still suspect there is some issue with that variable. What happens if you just remove it, how does the popover look? (Without that `contentSizeForViewInPopover` distraction). Your updated question (with image) does not show an empty view, perhaps there is more than one issue here. The problem does not lie in the code that you have reported though.

Comment: As I mention on my update " [self.activityPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:self.contentSizeForViewInPopover animated:YES];" now is showing content but is shop off.

Comment: @HelenaM, see my updated answer. I do understand the issues, so please follow my suggestions and report back.